# Does ZFC prove a sentence in the language of arithmetic that PA+Con(ZFC) cannot prove?

Tags: logic, set-theory, peano-axioms

Assume ZFC is consistent.

Then its clear that PA+Con(ZFC) proves a sentence whose translation cannot be proved by ZFC (namely, that ZFC is consistent).

Does ZFC prove a sentence in the language (relativized to $\omega$) of arithmetic that PA+Con(ZFC) cannot prove? I'm guessing "yes."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course. An example is the statement that [all Goodstein sequences terminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem). The point is that this sentence is not only independent of $\mathsf{PA}$, but in fact of the theory resulting from adding to $\mathsf{PA}$ all $\Pi^0_1$ statements true in the standard model of arithmetic. Note that $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is an example of such a $\Pi^0_1$ statement.

That Goodstein's theorem has this property follows from the standard proof of its independence using the method of indicators: One begins with a nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$; the argument produces an initial segment $I$ that satisfies $\mathsf{PA}$ but where Goodstein's theorem fails. Starting with a model of true arithmetic, the segment $I$ can be arranged to satisfy not just $\mathsf{PA}$, but the true $\Pi^0_1$ theory. A good reference is the book

> Petr Hájek, and Pavel Pudlák. **[Metamathematics of First-Order Arithmetic](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Metamathematics-of-First-Order-Arithmetic/toc/pl/1235421926)**, 2nd printing, Perspectives in Mathematical Logic, Volume 3, Berlin: Springer-Verlag, 1998. [MR1219738 (94d:03001)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1219738).

(You may find this related [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/468076/462) of some interest.)

Going beyond: Goodstein's theorem is $\Pi^0_2$. Adding all true $\Pi^0_2$ statements to $\mathsf{PA}$ does not prove all true $\Pi^0_3$ statements. Etc. And $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is strong enough to verify all this.

Comment: If $\phi$ is a new $\Pi_1$ sentence (of arithmetic) we've just added (to PA), which is unprovable in PA, and $\psi$ is a $\Pi_2$ sentence that we could already prove, then $\phi \wedge \psi$ is a new $\Pi_2$ sentence that we couldn't prove, but now can. So we can prove new $\Pi_2$ sentences. How do we know that Goodstein's theorem isn't one of them?

Comment: Let $T$ be the theory consisting of $\mathsf{PA}$ and all $\Pi^0_1$ sentences that are true in the standard model of arithmetic. If $T$ proves a statement $\phi$, say, Goodstein's theorem, then any model of $T$ is also a model of $\phi$. Since the structure $I$ from the second paragraph in my answer is a model of $T$ but not of Goodstein's theorem, it follows that $T$ does not prove this result. *A posteriori*, if $S$ is a subtheory of $T$, such as the one you mention in your comment, then $S$ cannot prove Goodstein's theorem either.