# Looking for counterexamples where the output of a computable function always has a computably checkable property, but PA cannot prove this

Tags: logic, computability, incompleteness, peano-axioms

Suppose we have a computable function $f$, say over the naturals, and a decidable set $S$ of naturals, such that $f(x) \in S$ for all $x$. In this case, for any specific $x$, there is some specific number $y$ such that Peano arithmetic proves $y = f(x)$. (This follows from the fact that $f$ is computable.) Moreover, by our supposition $y \in S$, and since $S$ is decidable, PA proves that $y \in S$. So PA proves the statements $f(1) \in S, f(2) \in S, f(3) \in S, ...$. But yet it might not prove $\forall x (f(x) \in S)$.

I would like to see an example of a function $f$ and set $S$ for which this situation obtains: that is, $f$ is computable and $S$ is decidable, and $\forall x (f(x) \in S)$, but PA does not prove this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An obvious example is the function $f$ that takes values $0$ and $1$, and $f(n)=1$ iff $n$ codes a proof in $\mathsf{PA}$ of "$0=1$". Here, $S=\{0\}$ but we cannot prove $\forall x\,(f(x)=0)$ because of the second incompleteness theorem.

We can modify this example easily: Let $S$ be *any* decidable set other than $\mathbb N$ and $\emptyset$. Let $m\notin S$, and consider any Turing machine $T$ that gives us a computable function $f$ with range contained in $S$ (that is, for any input $n$, $T$ halts with output in $S$). Modify $T$ to a new machine $T'$ so that with input $n$, if $n$ codes a contradiction as above, then $T'$ halts with output $m$. Else, $T'$ executes $T$ with input $n$ (and halts when $T$ does, with the same output). Here, $\forall x\, \hat f(x)\in S)$ is not provable, where $\hat f$ is the computable function given by $T'$. One can easily modify this example to include the case $S=\emptyset$, where "$f(x)\in S$" is understood as "$x$ is not in the domain of $f$" (or "$T$ does not halt with input $x$", if you wish).

For a more interesting example, consider the typical true $\Pi^0_2$ statements unprovable in $\mathsf{PA}$, such as the [strong Ramsey theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem), [Goodstein's theorem](http://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/goodsteins.pdf), [Hercules-Hydra theorem](http://math.andrej.com/2008/02/02/the-hydra-game/), the [Kanamori-McAloon theorem](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=870685), [etc](http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman.8/pdf/UnpThms110509.pdf). All these are statements of the form "For all $n$ there is an $m$ such that $\psi(n,m)$", where $\psi(n,m)$ is provable in $\mathsf{PA}$ for each $n$ and appropriate $m$. In fact, for each $n$, the statement $\exists y\,\psi(n,y)$ is provable. But the full statement $\forall x\exists y\,\psi(x,y)$ is unprovable. Note that any such statement comes associated with a computable function $g$, where $g(n)=m$ iff $\psi(n,m)$ (and $m$ is least possible; this last requirement can be easily added in each of these cases without affecting computability). You may want to look at the paper

> Laurie Kirby, and Jeff Paris. *Accessible independence results for Peano arithmetic*, Bull. London Math. Soc., **14 (4)**, (1982), 285–293. [MR0663480 (83j:03096)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=663480).

What Kirby and Paris do in that paper is to develop the method of *indicators* from which most of these results can be verified. They show how, starting from a nonstandard model $M$ of $\mathsf{PA}$, one can identify a proper initial segment $I$ of the model that is also a nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$ but such that $g$ is not a total function in $I$, that is, there is a nonstandard number $N$ such that $g(N)\in M\setminus I$.

For any such $g$, we can give an example of the property you are interested: Simply let $f(n)=0$ iff $\mathsf{PA}$ proves that $g(n)$ is defined. Here, $\mathsf{PA}$ cannot prove that $\forall x\,(f(x)=0)$ or, equivalently, that $g$ is total, since this would mean that $g$ is total in all nonstandard models, including $I$, where it is not. For a different approach, you may want to read on the [fast-growing hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy). This is a hierarchy of computable provably total functions indexed by ordinal numbers:

- $f_0(x)=x+1$.
- For $\alpha<\varepsilon_0$, $f_{\alpha+1}(n)=f_\alpha^n(n)$, where the superindex indicates that $f_\alpha$ is iterated $n$ times.
- For limit $\alpha<\varepsilon_0$, $f_\alpha(n)=f_{d(\alpha,n)}(n)$.

Here, $(d(\alpha,n)\mid n\in\mathbb N)$ is an explicitly given, strictly increasing sequence of ordinals with limit $\alpha$, and $\varepsilon_0$ is the supremum of the sequence $\omega,\omega^\omega,\omega^{\omega^\omega},\dots$, where exponentiation is in the ordinal sense (so all these are countable ordinals). A theorem of Wainer shows that if a computable function $f$ is provably total in $\mathsf{PA}$, then there is some $\alpha<\varepsilon_0$ such that $f(n)<f_\alpha(n)$ for all but finitely many values of $n$ (for a proof, look at the references in my paper on Goodstein's function). The function $g$ associated to the examples above actually satisfies that for each $\alpha<\varepsilon_0$, we have $f_\alpha(n)<g(n)$ for all but finitely many $n$. Any such fast-growing $g$ gives us an example of a computable $f$ with the unprovability property under discussion.

Comment: So I guess in this case $S = \{0\}$ -- correct?

Comment: @NickThomas Yes, I've added this together with additional examples.

Comment: Additional details on fast-growing functions, and references, can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/388559/462).

Comment: On indicators, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/37334/6085).