# Is any property of the number TREE($3$) known?

Tags: number-theory, big-numbers

The number TREE($3$) is an insane large number occuring in Ramsey theory.

For the usual large numbers constructed with Knut's up-arrow-notation, Conway chain-notation and Bowers array-notation, it is usually easy to determine the last few digits of the constructed number because mostly power towers with many identical entries come into play.

> Is that also the case for TREE($3$) ? I have read that no upper bound is known, but it might be that the number is known to be a huge power tower. So, can we determine the last digits of TREE($3$) ? Or do we know nothing, not even whether TREE($3$) is even or odd ?

Comment: Actually, parity of a number defined combinatorially isn't a property which we should even think of as "fundamental" or "easier to establish than others". For example, we don't know whether R(5,5) (Ramsey number) is odd or even, yet we know a lot more about it than about TREE(3).

Comment: Do we have any idea how large $R(5,5)$ is ?

Comment: Between 43 and 49 (inclusive)

Comment: Oops, very small, but we do not know which number it is, right ?

Comment: Indeed, this is everything we know about R(5,5). We don't know whether it's a prime, whether it's divisible by 5. For what we know, it could be any of the seven numbers in the range, and neither is more likely than the others.

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you for the info!

Comment: [Lower bound?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/93828/how-large-is-tree3)

Comment: @SimpleArt Of course, I mean an upper bound. Fixed.

Comment: This may be helpful to you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950116/where-does-treen-sit-on-the-fast-growing-hierarchy/1959090#1959090

Comment: TREE(3) is an incomprehensibly large number with a relatively simply definition, making it quite odd in this way. So if it were even, that would be an odd even number, so much that it would make it *even odder*.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, I have used the last binary (NOT decimal) digits of the tree steps and proven that it is odd and the last 3 binary digits are 011.

Comment: Reference/proof?