# How to compare big numbers that are outcome of different functions.

Tags: asymptotics, factorial, big-numbers

How is the best way to compare big numbers? They are result of two functions with different asymptotic growth. For example:

Googleplex which is $10^{{10}^{100}}$  to $1000!$

Comment: You might look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72646/help-me-put-these-enormous-numbers-in-order-googol-googol-plex-bang-googol-s

Comment: Take logarithms. Use Stirling's formula.

Comment: Apropos to Ross's comment, see [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27642031) as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$10^{googol}$ compared to $1000!$

$1000!=1000\times999\times998...<1000^{1000}$

$1000^{1000}=(10^3)^{1000}=10^{3000}$

since a googol is drastically larger than $3000$, the first number is much, much greater.

In general logarithms (equivalently, converting to a base and comparing exponents) are a great way for comparing large numbers. For example: whether $2^{523} <^? 3^{228}$ may not be obvious, but even knowing very rounded values for $\log(2)$ and $\log(3)$ will let you compare $523\log(2)$ and $228\log(3)$ quite easily, which is an equivalent problem.